# Class return wait for UIWebView

Tags: ios, class, uiwebview

i am developing an app to fetch data from my school website to a tableview, but to do that, the app needs to be logged in.

I have been trying for hours to make a proper login system by sending the data as POST to the login form, but for some reason, it wont work (i have done it before for another site, so it aint because i dont know how to)

So now i just have a hidden uiwebview with the loginform and populate that with what the user adds to two uitextfields..

but instead of adding that hidden uiwebview to every viewcontroller (whenever i need to login again to get data, in case of the session on the site expires) i would really like to just make a class to do that..

i was thinking about something like:

class.h

```
 +(BOOL)loginWithUsername(NSString*)username : password(NSString*)password;
```

class.m

```
+(BOOL)loginWithUsername(NSString*)username : password(NSString*)password {
 //create webview
 //populate form on site
 // press submitbutton
 //wait for - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView to finish, where it analyzes if the user was logged in, and if so return true
}
```

But how would this be done??

Comment: Does your schools server provide a login web service and not a form?

Comment: Instead of waiting, which could have bad UI behaviour, can you have your login post a notification when successful and let your controllers listen for that before showing new data?  …or pass a completion block to the login routine?

Comment: Phillips that sounds plossible, i will try that

Answer (score 0):

much better is create method with completion block

typedef for block, is not necessary but really helpful

```
typedef void(^CompletionHandler)(BOOL success);
```

in this method save completion handler to local ivar like `CompletionHandler _handler;`

```
+(BOOL)loginWithUsername(NSString*)username : password(NSString*)password complete:(CompletionHandler)handler;
```

in `webViewDidFinishLoad` check that login success end cal block with

```
if (handler)
{
      handler(YES); // or no if login failed
}
```

and in anther controller you can call this like

```
[LoginClass loginWithUsername:@"user" password:@"pass" complete:^(bool success){
     if (success) 
     {
       // logged in 
     }
}];
```

Comment: Okayso, i have tryed:
ServiceHandler.h
`
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
typedef void(^CompletionHandler)(BOOL success);

@interface ServiceHandler : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>

+(BOOL)loginWithUsername:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password complete:(CompletionHandler)handler;
@end
`

ServiceHandler.m: http://pastebin.com/jPAaF9mb

but it fail: http://i.imgur.com/pI6SSu3.png @sage444

Comment: allright now i i simply just 

`[ServiceHandler loginWithUsername:@"user" password:@"pass" complete:^(BOOL success){
            
            NSLog(@"Logget1");
        }];`

but i never get that log, it must not get completed @sage444